# Why was my KDE desktop switched with the Gnome one and how can I change it back?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kde, kubuntu

To clarify, I am still using KDE (Kubuntu specifically) but I also have Gnome installed.  However, when I log in, my plasma desktop shows up for a few seconds, but then switches to the Gnome desktop.  The plasma widgets disappear, the icons change, and the right-click menu is GTK themed and has the Gnome options rather than the KDE ones.

I've been messing with a lot of options over the past few days, but I think that this probably happened because I removed a lot of native apps (Amarok, Dragon Player, Movie Player, KMail, KTorrent, Transmission, and maybe a couple more).

Any ideas on how I can revert back to my KDE plasma desktop without a complete reinstallation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create (or edit) your `~/.xinitrc` file ($ represents your prompt, don't type it):

```
$gedit ~/.xinitrc
```

add this to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec startkde
```

make the file executable:

```
$chmod +x ~/.xinitrc
```

Let's link it to `~/.xsession` so it's read by GDM on startup:

```
ln -s ~/.xinitrc ~/.xsession
```

Reboot.

Now enter your username and click **sessions**. Select **default session** and it should load KDE.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't see the sysconfig folder or the .xinitrc file.  I'm running the latest stable versions of KDE, Gnome, and Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah. Ubuntu doesn't have /etc/sysconfig. The .xinitrc file isn't visible if you were looking for it in nautilus as it beings with a dot. If you were using the terminal to check, you probably don't have an .xinitrc yet.

Comment: You're most welcome! :)